# prevent jquery mobile from styling element

Tags: jquery-mobile

I've got a checkbox that I want hidden on the page.  My obvious first attempt was the following:

```
<input type='checkbox' style='display:none' />
```

However, I noticed jquery mobile automagically wraps the checkbox in a div that looks like this:

```
<div class='ui-checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox' style='display:none;' />
</div>
```

I would assume that there's some kind of `data-` element that would prevent this additional styling, but haven't found it in the docs or elsewhere.  It's easy enough to override the `.ui-checkbox` in css to hide it as well, but would prefer a more jquery mobile-standard approach.  Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The attribute that prevents styling is `data-role="none"`

```
<input type='checkbox' style='display:none' data-role="none" />
```

See the [Jquery doc](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/forms/): "Preventing auto-initialization of form elements"

Comment: Nice and easy.. and still is a valid solution in 2015, with the current version (1.4.5). http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/forms/#Preventingauto-initializationofformelements

Answer (score 9):

For future users.

Just in case you want to disable for every form element or your forms are loading dynamically where you cannot edit markup  use this.

```
        $(document).on('pagebeforecreate', function( e ) {
            $( "input, textarea, select", e.target ).attr( "data-role", "none" );
        });
```

Comment: and for future future users, the [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function is being deprecated in favor of the [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function, as of jQuery version 1.7

Answer (score 2):

I have too many places to change inputs and add data-role="none" 
The following code works for me:

```
 <script>
        $(document).bind('mobileinit',function(){
            $.mobile.page.prototype.options.keepNative = "select,input";
        });        
    </script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```