# Issue with changing radio button style

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am using radio button and check box in application I need to change the default style of radio button which is similar to following image,

```
Gender
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender_1" />
<label for="gender_1">Male</label>
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender_2" />
<label for="gender_2">Female</label>
```

From the above code I am getting like this,

[image]

But I don't need the button background. I need similar to the following,

[image]

In the same manner I need the same out put for check box also ,

```
  Account Status
<input type="radio" name="status" id="status_1" />
<label for="status_1">Non-Resident Indian (NRI)</label>
<input type="radio" name="status" id="status_2" />
<label for="status_2">Person of Indian Origin (PIO)</label>
<input type="radio" name="status" id="status_3" />
<label for="status_3">Oversean Citizen of Indian (OCI)</label>
<input type="radio" name="status" id="status_4" />
<label for="status_4">Foreign Tourist</label>
```

I don't need background for check box also,

[image]

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279327/prevent-jquery-mobile-from-styling-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form elements style is hard to change. Usually when you see not "default" element, it's images with hidden inputs somewhere near and it's values are changed dynamically by jquery/js

Checkbox/Radio:

```
<div class='fakeCheckbox'><input type='radio' style='display: none;'/></div> // image of radio button
$('.fakeCheckbox').click(function(){
    var input = $(this).find('input');
    input.attr('checked', !input.attr('checked'))
});
```

Dropdown:

```
<div class='fakeDrop'><span></span><select style='opacity: 0; position: absolute; left: 0; topL 0;'></div> // Only opacity, so you can click on it!
$('.fakeDrop > select').change(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('span').text($('option:selected', this).text());
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qznhrs5h/) [[v2]](http://jsfiddle.net/qznhrs5h/2/)

Comment: I am not clear. Please explain me how can I remove the label background So that I need output similar to 2nd image

Comment: @Precious It's clear: use images instead of real input fields. Than on all browsers input fields will look the same

Comment: Thank you. http://jsfiddle.net/manjunath_r/qznhrs5h/1/ . How can I set radio button and label text in same line

Comment: If I need same for check box. If change input type will that be enough?

Comment: @Precious no, you need to modify code for checkbox (check update)

Comment: That is how exactly I need. But I need to implement this in mobile. so If I use Jquery mobile then both radio button and check box clicks are not working? Any idea what is the reason for the same? http://jsfiddle.net/manjunath_r/qznhrs5h/3/

Comment: @Precious because there is `touch` and not `click` events. You can accept answer now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59657/discussion-between-justinas-and-precious).